# How to find parent process id in linux

Tags: linux

I was looking for a linux command to find the parent process id. When I use the following command
ps- ef | grep jboos

It returns all process ids including chile and some other information. What I am looging for is to filter out child ids and other information and return only parent id. So that calling app can kill all the running processes by just killing parent.

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

The `l` (lowercase `L`) option to `ps` will add the PPID column to the output.

Answer (score 3):

[getppid](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/functions/getppid.html) is the function that you require. In bash it is `$PPID`

eg

```
#!/bin/bash

echo $PPID;
```

Comment: How can I use $PPID? Can you please give me an example.